# Linking a discord channel that your bot made in a message Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I went looking on how to link the discord channel the bot just made in a message but was not able to find a solution that worked.

Here is my current code:

```js
    const guild = client.guilds.cache.get("1057116059750117426");

    const storageBuffer = fs.readFileSync("./src/Storage/storage.json");
    const storageData = JSON.parse(storageBuffer.toString());

    storageData.ticket_id++; // adds one to the ticket number
    const ticketId = storageData.ticket_id;

    await guild.channels.create({
      name: `TICKET-${ticketId}`,
      parent: "1057370813357109308",
    });


    const ChannelName = guild.channel.id
    //Here is were I want to link the channel 

    await interaction.update({
      ephemeral: true,
      content: `Your ticket has been submited \n You can view it here -> ${ChannelName}`,
      components: [],
      embed: [],
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`guild.channels.create`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannelManager?scrollTo=create) returns the channel created:

```js
let createdChannel = await guild.channels.create({
  name: `TICKET-${ticketId}`,
  parent: "1057370813357109308",
});
```

...so you can later use it in your message like this:

```js
content: `Your ticket has been submitted \n You can view it here -> ${createdChannel}`
```